# How to design an outrunner BLDC motor

Tags: design, motors

I've difficulties to find a good documentation or a book to how to design an outrunner BLDC motor. My propose is, defined RPM and approximative kW and some other parameters, which are calculation steps to design a BLDC? Objective is to design a motor for UAV and learning from this (and have fun).

What I've actually found is:

- Blogger with photos or videos of their projects with some parameters but without any design tips or design files;
- Highly theory books, very wide, but actually without any practical application;
- Some research documentation that treat only some aspects.

Since it's for hobby proposes, I'd like to avoid months or theory but learn with some simulation trial and error.

Comment: Are you building also the controller/driver of the BLDC motor?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean specify, not design?

Comment: I would find an old motor and tear it apart…and attempt to put it back together again to see if it works…you may also look on hackaday.com or on instructables or youtube, there are many tinkerers out there. You will unlikely find a DIY step by step instructions booklet on how to make a bldc motor (especially since they can be bought for little moneu nowadays) they arn‘t trivial to produce by hand.